# Android:Resize image to full width and height with Picasso just like instagram

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

In `RecyclerView`, images are shown as full height and width, and do not appear stretched, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Picasso.with(myContext).load(uri).resize(720, 720)
                    .centerCrop().into(aImageView);
```

I think it will work for your condition.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fixed_width_for_each_cell"
    android:layout_height="fixed_height_for_each_cell"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use only android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

ImageView.ScaleType     CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fixed_width_for_each_cell"
    android:layout_height="fixed_height_for_each_cell"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
   />
```

Center Inside property not change Image Aspect Ratio . and if you provide height and width to `ImageView` its resize image according Bitmap `Aspect Ratio` so its sure full image should be displayed.